# Pre-rendering single vue components not routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

I have been looking for a few hours for something that could help my problem, but as of now, I havent found it.

The problem is:

- I am working on an PHP/Latte server-side rendered website, where I have decided to implement Vue. However, since there is no possibility for me to change this website into an SPA, I need to just create micro components with Vue and use them inside the BE templates.
- By that I mean that there is a `.latte` template, where I insert a `<My_component />` element, which gets rendered client side.

Which is fine for some components, but others, like the main menu, product or something else important for SEO purposes, needs to be somehow pre-rendered for crawlers.

By now I have read 10+ articles and watched 4 videos on `prerender-spa-plugin`, which I am sure is a great solution for SPAs, but I dont think it would work for my case. Especially since I am not using Vue router.

Nuxt.js also seems like not what I want and would be a bit of an overkill in my case.

Basically I just need a webpack or Node based plugin, that would take `.vue` files, that I would need to be pre-rendered, and create (build) the static HTML for them. Which would be either automatically or by hand inserted into the `.latte` template.

**Has anyone had any experience with this?**

Comment: Rendertron might be a possible solution but you'll need to host it externally. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron

Comment: Thank I will try it out @PhilipFeldmann

Comment: @Jousi what path did you take? Have you found any neat solution for that? I have a very similar case in which I want to prerender individual .vue files for me to later include them in my templates.